# RESTeasy ContainerRequestFilter is never being called

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jboss, resteasy

I'm trying to implement an authentication filter with RESTeasy 3.0.17FINAL in Tomcat 8. Here I have my `web.xml` entries.

```
<!-- RESTEasy Config -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Here I have my test API

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestAPI extends APIServlet {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @AllowUsers
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("status", "awesome");
        json.addProperty("yeah", "It worked");
        return Response.ok(json).build();
    }
}
```

And here is my temporary filter:

```
@Provider
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            containerRequestContext.abortWith(Response.status(403).build());
        }
        System.out.println("Filtered");
    }
}
```

My filter is never being called. The println is never reached, I can't successfully place breakpoints in the filter. There are no error messages in the cataline or localhost logs. I have tried using name-binding annotations as such:

```
@NameBinding
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Secured {
}
```

With `@Secured` right above `@Provider` on `AuthFilter` and above `@GET` on `printMessage`. That doesn't work either.

I have tried explicitly listing the filter in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myPackage.mvc.servlet.API.AuthFilter</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Why is my filter never being called? I have two other classes marked `@Provider` and they are being recognized by the system and I can place breakpoints in them and they are working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Jersey instead of RESTeasy and everything just worked.

Comment: Your REST endpoint needs to call @Secured above the method (or class) you want secured

Answer (score 1):

Add a Provider file under your `META-INF/services`, like: `/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers`.

`javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` is a file, the content is your path of filter like:

```
com.hujiang.foe.instalment.liquidation.biz.impl.account.filter.ContextCleanFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@PreMatching` or `@PostMatching` to your `ContainerRequestFilter`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've tried that and it didn't work. I can try again when I'm back at my computer

Comment: I'm not using Tomcat, but `@Privoder` didn't work for me. I manually add the filter instance to resteasy providerFactory like `ResteasyproviderFactory.getContainerRequestFilterRegistry().registerSingleton(new AuthFilter());`